# Delphi, is possible have a property and function with the same name?

Tags: delphi

consider this code

```
type
  TMyObject=class
  private
    FName: Integer;
    function Name: Integer;
  public
    property Name : Integer read FName;
    function Name(Param1 : integer) : Integer; overload;
  end;
```

Is possible in delphi create a property and a function (or procedure) with the same name?

Exist any directive or compiler switch which allow create a class like that?

Comment: How would the parser distinguish between them?

Comment: You don't need to ask this question, you can work the answer out for yourself. How could the compiler distinguish between the no parameter Name function and the Name property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not. In addition, there is no directive or compiler switch that would allow this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the error message that you got when you tried this...you did try it right?

Comment: Yes, i try, and i knew about the message error, but i make this question because maybe exist a directive or a compiler switch wich allows create a class like this.

Comment: For the benefit of other readers, can you tell what the error message is?

Comment: That is the message `[DCC Error] ProjectTest.dpr(14): E2004 Identifier redeclared: 'Name'`

Answer (score 0):

Since i see the `overload` keyword. I suspect that perhaps what you need default are parameters

If you use

```
function Name(Param1: Integer = SOME_VALUE): Integer;
```

it can be called as either `:=Name` or `:=Name(5)`

Comment: What you write is true, but it does not really answer the question (having a function and a property with the same name). If it's read-only it won't make much difference but as soon as it's a read-write-property it will.

Comment: Smasher: but it's not read-write, so the two are equivalent in this case. The answer to the OP question is "no", and has already been given.

Comment: Obviously the answer is no. But I tried to guess what he was doing and what he might actually need, that's why I suggested the above code.

Answer (score 0):

By accident I discovered it is possible to have a class with a property that has the same name as a function in the parent class (or vice versa).

However, I would avoid this because it will confuse you. Especially if the function and property have different meanings!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the compiler cannot do what you want.
In theory, a future version of the compiler could:

The signature of a method (overloaded or not) consists of the name and the parameter types.
The same holds for the signature of indexed properties.
Since the signature spaces of properties and methods are partially linked (hence the compiler error message), that combined space could be extended to include property overloads.

Of course that extension can backfire because of backward compatibility.

--jeroen

Comment: (btw: fully qualified parameter types. Afaik the unitname of the type is also in there.)

Comment: @Marco: the unit and class name form the parent path to the signature spaces I meant.

Comment: Since both declarations look the same, you can write something like this: `X := Name;` The compiler needs to work out what version of "Name" you want before it can look at hidden signatures / mangled names. And if you're supposed to give it a hand, you might as well call one Name_A and the other Name_B, and that works just fine with the current compiler.

Comment: @Cosmin: of course it is easier to rename. I'm not arguing that the compiler should be extended, just phrasing that theoretically it could be.